# How to check if user input has the correct type Java

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I want to check if the user gives a float as an input. In this case I tried the if statement to call a text when user gives a String instead of a number.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
class Main {public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  
System.out.println("Enter your age");

Float age = myObj.nextFloat();  

if (myObj instanceof String) {
    System.out.println("You have to give a number");

System.out.println("Age is: " + age); 
}
}
}
```

But an error appears. Does it have something to do with "myObj"?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you read the documentation of the `nextFloat` method?

Comment: `myObj instanceof String` will always be `false`, since `myObj` is a `Scanner` and never a `String`. Also, with `nextFloat` you'll get an exception if a user enters anything but a floating point value.